# Discord.js Sending a message to another channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js, message, roles

I currently have a working script that assigns roles based on the args that the poster inputs.
What I am trying to do is have the bot send a message to the local channel so the poster knows that it worked and then send another message to another channel welcoming the user who got the roles to the server. This is what I have:

```
const { client } = require('../main.js');


module.exports = {
    name: 'roles',
    description: "This is the command to give new recruits their role!",
    args: true,
    usage: '<department> <@user>',
    execute(message, args){

        //variables are defined here

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('the channel id');
        message.delete(); //This deletes the posters command message

        if (!message.mentions.users.size){
            return message.channel.send('Please make sure to tag someone!');
             
        else if(args[0] === 'bcso'){
            user.roles.add(bcso);
            user.roles.add(member);
            user.roles.add(whitelist)
            user.roles.remove(leoR);
            message.channel.send(`${user} is now a full member of the BCSO`);
            channel.send('Message goes here');
        }
   //rest of my code
```

But the error I'm getting in the console is: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined"

Just to confirm I have an advanced code handler set up so this code is inside of a commands folder in its own file.

Ideas?

Comment: Try passing client as an `execute()` parameter and reference it that way instead of importing it from another file

Comment: @Elitezen so just add it in with the the other two?  So ```execute(message, args, client) ```?

Comment: Yes, just make sure the order of parameters are the same throughout all files

Comment: Do I have to add it into the command files that don't even reference it?

Comment: Yes, all parameters should be identical in order and size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your imported `client` is not defined. Maybe because you don't export it correctly in your `main.js` file.

Luckily you can simply use the message to find the channel. To do that you need to change `client.channels.cache.get('the channel id');` to `message.client.channels.cache.get('ID HERE');`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that and Im pretty sure it didn't error but it also didn't post the message. I know the ID is right. The only thing I can think of is that the channels name uses discord fonts to change the font which causes issues tagging it in a message but I've never had issues with that when referencing them as their ID in embedded messages.

Comment: can you do a `console.log(channel)` to see if your channel actually gets found?

Comment: Didn't think of that. I'll try it and let you know

Comment: I must have messed it up the first time, cause it worked. Thanks!